# How to select multiple values in selectize plugin from controller

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object, selectize.js

How to add few options as selected
I am using this plugin: https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md

I have an object like shown in below image:
[image]

**This my my CLient script**

```
//skills
$scope.$selectSkill = $('#selectSkill').selectize({
    valueField: 'id',
    labelField: 'name',
    searchField: 'name',
    placeholder: "Select Skills",
    options: $scope.data.skills,
    create: false,
    sortField: {
        field: 'name',
        direction: 'asc'
    }
});
```

**This is my HTML**

```
<select id="selectSkill" 
name="selectSkill" 
ng-model="selectSkill" 
multiple required> </select>
```

and this how it's loading so far everything is good,
[image]

Now when i trigger a method i will get some(**two**) values like this in response:

```
48c9eda9c0a8018b4b6aca082d5d1e41  ,  48c9fe9ac0a8018b6a37e4db0d07df09
```

I want these two get selected as shown in below image
[image]

How can I do it..?

I have tried something like this:

```
var $select = $("#selectSkill").selectize();
                var yourDefaultIds = [slectedSkills.skills];  //(those 2 vlaues)
                selectize.setValue(yourDefaultIds);;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//populate skills starts here
var templateSkills = finTempObj.skills;
var str_array_skills = templateSkills.split(',');
var $select =   $("#selectSkill").selectize();
var selectize = $select[0].selectize;
selectize.setValue(str_array_skills);
selectize.refreshOptions();
//populate skills ends here
```

This should work I have tested it.
instead of setting as string convert those two values as an array then set.